# joins in table is not working properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below three tables which are joined among themselves. The tables names are

```
1) i IOA_INVOICE_LINE
2)  IOA_INVOICE_LINE_NOTES
3) IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP
```

An image is attached which will graphically shows you the relationship. I am trying to get the count of inv_line_note_id  from IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP table with respect to each id column in the ioa_invoice_line table. Please advise how to get the count of column  inv_line_note_id of IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP table with context to id column in the ioa_invoice_line table .

As advised I have added sample data:

```
IOA_INVOICE_LINE  :- 

ID             VERSION
1234            Abc


IOA_INVOICE_LINE_NOTES :-

ID       INLI_ID        NOTES
345      1234           Aqou


INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP :-

ID      INV_LINE_NOTE_ID        ATTACHEMENT
23            345                 rtfffr
24            345                 fhgygg
```

below is the query which was implemented but its not working as it is showing the result as 0 which should note be as there i the expected value should  2 as the there is total 2 rows in the table  INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP with correspond to  column id 1234 of IOA_INVOICE TABLE please advise how to get the total count of  column  inv_line_note_id of IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP table with context to id column in the ioa_invoice_line table

```
select ioa_invoice_line.id, count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.attachment_blob_id) as totalAttachment
from ioa_invoice_line
     left outer join ioa_invoice_line_notes 
              on ioa_invoice_line.id = ioa_invoice_line_notes.inli_id
     left outer join IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP 
              on ioa_invoice_line_notes.id = IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id
              where  ioa_invoice_line.id =1234 
GROUP BY ioa_invoice_line.id;
```

have also attached the image that will show the relationship
[image to show the relationship among three tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52rKR.jpg)

Comment: Did you try `count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id)` instead of `count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.attachment_blob_id)`?

Comment: @tr yes but still it is not working , please advise how to overcome from this problem

Comment: Found it: your last join condition is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @trincot Thanks its works now also please advise lets see i only want to see the results where the count of IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id that is count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) is greater than 0 then how i will modify the query

Comment: You can achieve that by turning the `left outer join`s into `inner join`s. But if your condition would be something else on the `count`, then you can use the `having` clause after the `group by`. It works like a `where`, but acts after the grouping has happened, and you can reference `count`, etc.

Comment: @trincot Thanks could you post the query please so that i can grasp that part also,Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last join condition is wrong as it compares two primary keys (both are `id`):

Instead:

```
select ioa_invoice_line.id, count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) as totalAttachment
from ioa_invoice_line
     left outer join ioa_invoice_line_notes 
              on ioa_invoice_line.id = ioa_invoice_line_notes.inli_id
     left outer join IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP 
              on ioa_invoice_line_notes.id = IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID
              where  ioa_invoice_line.id =1234 
GROUP BY ioa_invoice_line.id;
```

Notice the `INV_LINE_NOTE_ID`.

I would also suggest to count `IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id` if your interest is to count records. If however, you want to exclude any records for which `attachment_blob_id` is `null` (can it be?), then keep the count as you had it.

#### Addendum: conditions on count

If you want to only get records where `count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) > 0` then turn the left outer joins into inner joins:

```
select ioa_invoice_line.id, count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) as totalAttachment
from ioa_invoice_line
     inner join ioa_invoice_line_notes 
              on ioa_invoice_line.id = ioa_invoice_line_notes.inli_id
     inner join IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP 
              on ioa_invoice_line_notes.id = IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID
              where  ioa_invoice_line.id =1234 
GROUP BY ioa_invoice_line.id;
```

But if your condition would be something else on the count, then you can use the `having` clause after the group by. It works like a `where`, but acts after the grouping has happened, and you can reference aggregates like `count`, etc.

For instance, if you would be interested only in cases where  `count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) > 2`, then you would write:

```
select ioa_invoice_line.id, count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) as totalAttachment
from ioa_invoice_line
     inner join ioa_invoice_line_notes 
              on ioa_invoice_line.id = ioa_invoice_line_notes.inli_id
     inner join IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP 
              on ioa_invoice_line_notes.id = IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID
              where  ioa_invoice_line.id =1234 
GROUP BY ioa_invoice_line.id
HAVING count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) > 2;
```

Comment: hanks its works now also please advise lets see i only want to see the results where the count of IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id that is count(IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP.id) is greater than 0 then how i will modify the query